# Using PowerBI DAX, Count duplicates without grouping (How many times the Order_ID is repeated?)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table of Orders (Order_ID; Product_ID) which in most of case shows more than one Product_ID in one Order_ID.

With keeping the same format, i want a measure to return the count of Product_ID for each Order_ID.

Note, i don't want to group by Order_ID, so i want to keep the duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
CountDups= COUNTROWS(FILTER(yourtable; yourtable[Order_ID] = EARLIER(yourtable[Order_ID]) && yourtable[Product_ID] = EARLIER((yourtable[Product_ID ]))))
```

It matches all Product_ID and Order_ID with other rows and counts them.

Comment: It worked as a column, but when i try to create a measure it is not working!

Comment: Glad I could help, please mark question as answered.